# Can I take a folding bicycle (no battery) about 16 inches (weight 7-9 kg) on board without paying extra?

Tags: air-travel, airports, guangzhou

[image]

I want to take my folding bicycle on board the plane from Guangzhou airport to Pakistan.

Comment: probably not; ask the airline.

Comment: What is the folded size of the bicycle (length, width, height)? Do you have a bag or box to hold it? What airline are you flying with?

Answer (score 2):

You could transport your folding bicycle as checked baggage, not as carry on, but would likely be charged a fee. While the weight is within the usual allowance for baggage, its dimensions would probably exceed airline restrictions.

Your bike (or example), the Anchor, measures 22” x 29” x 12” folded and weighs 30 pounds. Generally, airlines do allow such items, but usually require they be bagged or boxed (and limit liability as a condition).

The only way to know for certain whether you can, and any fees, is to contact the airline.